# Error while install Android Studio in Linux

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-14.04

While  Installing Android-studio  The java error come occur in mid
I install Android-studio in Ubuntu 14.04

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3952940.zip': Read timed out
    , response: 200 OK

    Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3952940.zip': Read timed out
    , response: 200 OK.

    java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-3965150.zip': Read timed out
    , response: 200 OK

    Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-3965150.zip': Read timed out
    , response: 200 OK.

    java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r25.0.3-linux.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    , response: 200 OK

    Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r25.0.3-linux.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    , response: 200 OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SDK folder has the right permissions(Owned by You instead of root.)
Otherwise, You can change the Installation Partition to one you have access to.